# How to get print to match print preview

Tags: printing

I've had this issue across multiple printers but. I took a picture with my iPhone and transfer it to my MacBookPro running 11.4 via AirDrop

[image]

I open the image in Preview which looks correct

[image]

I pick File->Print and the print preview looks correct

[image]

I then print and the print is **not** correct

[image]

How do I get my Mac to print correctly?

Comment: what about trying to print it in landscape ?

Comment: no luck in landscape. Same issue. good guess though

Comment: I wonder if the document has a different page size. Get info on the PDF and see what the page size is under the general tab. I've seen "odd" page sizes do those kind of things to a PDF print out...

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to what @Steve Chambers said, your "Paper Size" setting is set to "US Legal" when it appears your printing on US Letter. You should change your "Paper Size" setting to match what you're printing on and that should fix it!